# Semantic information collections on the web. (Semantic Wikipedia)

Tags: reference-request, semantics, data-sets, knowledge-representation, ontologies

There are lots of technologies supporting semantic information markup even as wiki software.

I am wondering if there is any kind of broad information collection project like Wikipedia which features semantic markup of those information.

Google didn't bring up a project like this (only for very specific topics like software) or i just didn't find the right keyword.

Does anyone know about something like this?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a computer science question, but I'll let the community decide.

Comment: Maybe it is because i'm searching for this information to use it for computer science experiments :-). It fits better to computer science than to Stackoverflow at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/About) provides structured information from Wikipedia.

It uses [RDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework), and is one of the most known [Linked Data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_data) datasets.

Also of interest (but not using information from Wikipedia) may be [Freebase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freebase) and [OpenCyc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyc#OpenCyc).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Exactly what i was looking for.